# Error message when setting parity for serial on rasp pi 3

Tags: python, pi-3, uart

I am trying to get the uart serial to work but when I try to set the parity the following error comes out.

```
pi@pi3:~ $ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0')
>>> ser.parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 347, in setParity
    if self._isOpen: self._reconfigurePort()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 413, in _reconfigurePort
    termios.tcsetattr(self.fd, TERMIOS.TCSANOW, [iflag, oflag, cflag, lflag, ispeed, ospeed, cc])
termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument')
>>>
```

I've been looking for similar problems on the web but to no success.
Please help!

Comment: Some possible causes here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496195/cant-open-serial-connection-in-pyserial-termios-error-22-invalid-argument

Comment: You probably have a Python error, but the secondary port doesn't support parity.

Comment: Thank you Steve and Milliways. I guess I have to reinstall Python, disable bluetooth and use the primary port.

Answer (score 1):

On a Raspberry Pi 3, the `/dev/ttyS0` attached to the GPIO RX/TX header pins is the less capable mini-UART and it doesn't do parity.

Relative the to more capable UART that was repurposed to Bluetooth on the wireless-capable RPi's, the port now has:

- No break detection
- No framing errors detection
- No parity bit
- No receive timeout interrupt
- No DCD, DSR, DTR or RI signals

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md  or look in section 2.2 of the datasheet at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf

It is possible to use a `/boot/config.txt` directive to turn off bluetooth, or switch the UART controlling the Bluetooth.

```
dtoverlay=dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
#dtoverlay=dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
```

I've tested the `/boot/config.txt`  `dtoverlay=dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` line on my Raspberry Pi Zero W and it works within python-serial minicom to set the port to 1200 7 bit, odd parity, 2 stop bits.  I haven't tested the miniUART for Bluetooth on the RPi-Zero-W.